# Executing script in background using Selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: perl, selenium, phantomjs

I am currently using [**ChromeDriver**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) for some [Selenium::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Chrome) automation scripts.

I can find no way to run that as a background process.

I tried using [Selenium::PhantomJS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::PhantomJS) module and [**PhantomJS**](http://phantomjs.org/) WebDriver but it is throwing some error. Since I cannot see the execution, how can I know where the problem occurred?

> Is there any setting to see the execution of PhantomJS?

Comment: So you have abandoned ChromeDriver in favour of PhantomJS just to get your process to run in the background?

Comment: Yeah cause the scripts will be deployed on a server and clients want that script must run in background.

Comment: So you don't think you can run a script involving ChomeDriver as a background process?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get any way to make ChromeDriver hide the chrome browser window during execution.

Comment: IIRC you are right that you can't use the ChromeDriver in the background. Can you update with the errors you are getting trying to run with PhantomJS?

Comment: I am trying to login to a site and using PhantomJS it is throwing error -Error while executing command: clickElement: An operation did not complete before its timeout expired.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an issue with the web site you are attempting to interact with?  Have you tried interacting with a different web site?

Comment: Also, if you post your code it would help.

Comment: Are you misunderstanding what *background* means? If you simply don't want the Chrome window displayed then close the window. That is completely different from running a *background* process which usually has no parent process and runs at a low priority. There is no reason why a background process shouldn't have a GUI window, but it is unusual.

Comment: @Borodin If I close the browser window will my task of site interaction not stop??

Comment: @Mohit: I'm sorry, I should have said *minimise* the window.

Comment: @Borodin there is a {maximize_window} function in [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) but no function to minimize the window

Comment: @Mohit: You're right, that's very odd. An alternative would be to `set_window_position(-2000, 0)` to move the window out of sight off the screen, or you could use `capture_screenshot('filename.png')` with PhantomJS to save the contents of the window when the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try running PhantomJS in the foreground.  To run on a server you need a headless browser like PhantomJS.  PhantomJS is headless when run either foreground or background. :-) If your server is linux you can still run chromedriver on the server but you will need [XVFB](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747).

Comment: The Server will we Windows Server and how to run PhantomJS on foreground, will I be able to see the script execution in a browser window for PhantomJS ?

Comment: If I understand your question no.  Headless is headless. Clients have displays and hence browsers. Servers do not have displays (in general) so you have to run headless.  Just run selenium the way you always run it just point to phantomJS as your browser.  You can watch the log (console) but no physical displayed browser. That is why they call it headless.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to debug locally using chromedriver then run on the continuous Integration (CI) server using phantomJS, SauceLabs, BrowserStack, or some combination there of. It is fine to run PhantomJS locally its just that you cannot see what the browser is displaying. In rare instances, the app uses JavaScript that PhantomJS can't support. For that client I used chromedriver coupled with XVFB on the **Linux** CI server.

Comment: My code is working smoothly in Chrome but giving error when switching to PhantomJS

Comment: What error? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).